# Create bins with totals and percentage

Tags: awk

I would like to create bins to get histogram with totals and percentage, e.g. starting from 0.

If possible to set the minimum and maximum value in the bins ( in my case value min=0 and max=20 )

**Input file**

```
8  5
10 1
11 4
12 4
12 4
13 5
16 7
18 9
16 9
17 7
18 5
19 5
20 1
21 7
```

**output desired**

```
      0 0        0.0%
 0 -  2 0        0.0%
 2 -  4 0        0.0%
 4 -  6 0        0.0%
 6 -  8 0        0.0%
 8 - 10 5        6.8%
10 - 12 5        6.8%
12 - 14 13      17.8%
14 - 16 0        0.0%
16 - 18 23      31.5%
18 - 20 19      26.0%
   > 20 8       11.0%
---------------------
Total: 73
```

I use this code from Mr Ed Morton, it works perfectly but the percentage is missed.

```
awk 'BEGIN { delta = (delta == "" ? 2 : delta) }
{
    bucketNr = int(($0+delta) / delta)
    cnt[bucketNr]++
    numBuckets = (numBuckets > bucketNr ? numBuckets : bucketNr)
}
END {
    for (bucketNr=1; bucketNr<=numBuckets; bucketNr++) {
        end = beg + delta
        printf "%0.1f %0.1f %d\n", beg, end, cnt[bucketNr]
        beg = end
    }
}' file
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your expected output doesn't seem to correspond to your sample input data, but try this variation of that `awk` code in your question (Intended to be put in an executable file to run as a script, not a a one-liner due to size):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { delta = (delta == "" ? 2 : delta) }
{
    bucketNr = int(($0+delta) / delta)
    cnt[bucketNr]++
    max[bucketNr] = max[bucketNr] < $2 ? $2 : max[bucketNr]
    sum += $2
    numBuckets = (numBuckets > bucketNr ? numBuckets : bucketNr)
}
END {
    for (bucketNr=1; bucketNr<=numBuckets; bucketNr++) {
        end = beg + delta
        printf "%d-%d %d %.1f\n", beg, end, max[bucketNr],
            (cnt[bucketNr] / NR) * 100
        beg = end
    }
    print "-------------"
    print "Total " sum
}
```

It adds tracking the maximum of the second column for each bin the first column falls in, and prints out a percentage instead of a count of how many rows were in each bin. Plus some tweaks to the output format to better match your desired output.

Comment: Thks a lot for the update code, please can u adapt it with the min and max as my updated output file..